Tamper detection
I am working on a tamper detection system for a drone using an STM32F103C8T6 microcontroller and a Quectel EC200U-CN GSM module. Here's an overview of the setup and my query:
The tamper box has a button underneath it. When the box is opened, the button is released, and the system should send an SMS alert.
If the drone's main battery (25000mAh) is disconnected during tampering, an external power source (e.g., a lithium-ion battery or Duracell battery) will power the STM32F103C8T6.
To conserve power during external battery operation, I plan to put the STM32F103C8T6 into standby mode.
I have the following questions:

Standby Mode Verification: How can I programmatically or externally verify that the STM32F103C8T6 has entered standby mode?
Power Connection: Which specific pins or connections should be used on the STM32F103C8T6 to connect the external battery while ensuring smooth operation during main battery disconnection?
Best Practices: Are there any additional recommendations for optimizing power consumption and ensuring reliable tamper detection and SMS transmission in this setup?


There is a lot that can go wrong while trying to send an SMS (even once it's with the network), so it'll be an indicator at best, and not remotely a certainty.
Depending on what you're trying to achieve, it's often better to use dedicated tamper detection functionality in a secure microcontroller (i.e: not an STM32F103),... you could store encryption keys in volatile memory, or maintain an "I'm okay!" flag that is inserted during production and which gets lost during tampering or power loss. It may be acceptable for you to send this SMS when main power returns, and you notice the "I'm okay!" flag is invalid... but by then, the firmware is likely compromised, etc...

How can I programmatically or externally verify that the STM32F103C8T6 has entered standby mode?

During R&D? Measure power consumption.
In the field? What's the use-case / purpose of this?

Which specific pins or connections should be used on the STM32F103C8T6 to connect the external battery while ensuring smooth operation during main battery disconnection?

The STM32F103 manual will document which pins require power for a given state of operation. If you're after a low power sleep, then this probably includes all power pins (and you'll need to design a supply failover mechanism)... if you're only hoping to maintain the RTC and retain data in the backup registers, then just the Vbat pin is likely enough.

Are there any additional recommendations for optimizing power consumption and ensuring reliable tamper detection and SMS transmission in this setup?

The concept you're describing is like a "dying gasp"... These are typically facilitated by bulk capacitance, a super capacitor, and/or a small secondary cell. Note that cellular modems can consume considerable current while transmitting (multiple amps for brief periods) - a battery is likely your best option, and any power saving efforts in the STM32 will almost certainly be dwarfed by the modem's energy usage while communicating with the network (or attempting to do so).
